# Given custom range, how can I find all the combinations of n numbers in that range which result a target average?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Suppose I want to have all combinations of 10 items from 83 to 86 which have the average of 84. Some of the solutions would be:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 83 | 84 | 85 | 86 |
+----+----+----+----+
|  0 | 10 |  0 |  0 |
|  1 |  8 |  1 |  0 |
|  2 |  6 |  2 |  0 |
|  3 |  4 |  3 |  0 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Is there a known algorithm to find the combinations that I'm looking for? Especially if there's one written in C# I'd appreciate it.

Comment: This is a specialized [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) ("the average must be 84", with a fixed number of items, can be rewritten as "the total sum must be `n` * 84"), specifically the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). The fact that the numbers are consecutive integers from a range probably allows for an efficient algorithm (unlike the fully general case), although a simple brute force search seems quite feasible as well, with such a small `n`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert what if the "average" is not so simple? What if it needs to be calculated with a special formula?

Comment: Since the "simple" case (subset-sum) is already NP-complete, more complicated ones aren't going to have easier algorithms. For small `n`, brute forcing still seems feasible. For potentially unbounded `n` and an arbitrary formula to determine if a set matches, you're likely looking at much more complicated stuff like Monte Carlo simulations or simulated annealing -- these wouldn't necessarily give you all possible solutions, however. Realistically, though, you'd probably take a look at the formula to see if there isn't a better way than just trying everything.

Comment: @JeroenMostert What if I wanted to do the bruteforce but wanted to do it multithreaded? How can I do that?

Comment: LINQ's `Enumerable.AsParallel`, `Parallel.For`, `Parallel.ForEach` are the simplest approaches (as opposed to writing your own custom threading). If you think of it as having 10 positions each with 4 possible values, all you have to do is enumerate all 10000 possible combinations (by translating a number into the set of numbers it represents) and evaluate them for solutionhood.

Comment: Do you really want an average or do you have a more complicated criterion? For average, there is a reasonably simple recursive algorithm to generate all possibilities, but i don't know if it's worth posting if it's not what you actually looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a trivial linear combination.  Subtract 84 from each value; they are now [-1, 0, 1, 2].  `0` is a filler value -- it doesn't affect the average.  Naming the counts `a-d`, we have:

```
a, b, c, d >= 0
a = c + 2d
a + b + c + d = 10
```

This makes the solution pretty quick to handle with brute force.  loop through possible values for `c` and `d`; compute the resulting `a` and `b` values, and print.  Note that your loops can be limited with the other restrictions:

```
for d in [0 .. 3]
    for c in [0 .. (10 - 3*d) / 2]   // c can take only half the remaining count;
                                     // a gets the rest.
        a = c + 2*d
        b = 10 - (a + c + d)
        print (a, b, c, d)
```

Output:

```
0 10 0 0
1 8 1 0
2 6 2 0
3 4 3 0
4 2 4 0
2 7 0 1
3 5 1 1
4 3 2 1
5 1 3 1
4 4 0 2
5 2 1 2
6 1 0 3
```

That's the gist; implementation details are left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)